# Android layout auto height

Tags: android, layout, view, height

I'm have some troubles with layout height

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingTop="2dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_name_label"
    style="@style/event_detail_label"
    android:text="@string/calendar_name_label" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendars_place_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

calendars_place_holder is layout where is store text views,

and the whole layout is high as there is only one text view in calendars_place_holder where as there are 3 or 4,

Can I have some advices ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to give width to the textview

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/calendar_name_label"
style="@style/event_detail_label"
android:text="@string/calendar_name_label" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: layout_widht and layout_height are already set in style="@style/event_detail_label"

Comment: I think the problem is the textview take whole width. So try to put this in textview and the layout to share whole width: android:layout_weight="0.5"